# Как правильно использовать if-else для радиокнопки?

Tags: java, swing

Есть фрейм, в котором создаю радиокнопки:

```
rbg = new ButtonGroup();

addDirectRadioButton("Подразделения", "SELECT * FROM DEPT");
addDirectRadioButton("Сотрудники", "SELECT * FROM EMP");
addDirectRadioButton("Разрядная сетка", "SELECT * FROM SALGRADE");

addButton = new JButton("Ввод");
addButton.setToolTipText("Ввести новые данные в таблицу");
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
});

public final void addDirectRadioButton(String name, final String query) {
    boolean selected = query.equals(DEFAULT_QUERY);
    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(name, selected);
    rbg.add(button);
    directPanel.add(button);

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            dbtm.executeUpdate(query);
        }
    };
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

И есть кнопка, в которую нужно поместить `if-else`. В зависимости от того, какая кнопка выбрана, должен открываться один из трех фреймов, к примеру: `AddDeptFrame`, `AddEmpFrame` и `AddSalgradeFrame`. Как правильно построить `if-else` для моей кнопки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if-else` в обработчике нажатия на кнопку - не очень хороший подход, т.к. если появятся новые варианты, код придется менять как на участке создания радиокнопок, так и в обработчике, и можно допустить ошибку. Удобнее сделать универсальный обработчик, и поместить разные варианты действий в коллекцию.

Код пользуется тем, что `ButtonGroup` может возвращать модель выбранной радиокнопки.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class RadioFrames extends JFrame {

    // таблица соответствия моделей кнопок фабрикам, создающим нужные фреймы
    HashMap<ButtonModel, Supplier<JFrame>> radioToFrames = new HashMap<>();
    ButtonGroup rbg = new ButtonGroup(); 
    JPanel directPanel = new JPanel();

    public RadioFrames() {
        JPanel content = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

        content.add( directPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        // используются method reference из java 8
        addDirectRadioButton("Подразделения", AddDeptFrame::new, true );
        addDirectRadioButton("Сотрудники", AddEmpFrame::new, false );
        addDirectRadioButton("Разрядная сетка", AddSalgradeFrame::new, false );

        JButton addButton = new JButton( "Ввод" );

        addButton.addActionListener( event -> {
            // rbg.getSelection() возвращает нам модель выбранной кнопки
            //   или null, если ничего не выбрано.
            // radioToFrames.get( null ) - допустимый вызов, и просто вернет 
            //   null, т.к. в таблице нет такого ключа
            Supplier<JFrame> frameSupplier = radioToFrames.get( rbg.getSelection() );
            // если в таблице есть фабрика для такой модели,
            //   создаем и показываем новый фрейм
            if ( frameSupplier != null ) {
                frameSupplier.get().setVisible( true );
            }
        });

        content.add( addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        setContentPane( content );
    }

    public void addDirectRadioButton( String name, Supplier<JFrame> frameSupplier, boolean selected ) {
        JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton( name, selected );
        rbg.add(button);
        directPanel.add(button);

        // добавляем в карту пару (модель -> фабрика)
        radioToFrames.put( button.getModel(), frameSupplier );
    }

    public static void makeUI() {
        RadioFrames mainFrame = new RadioFrames();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( RadioFrames::makeUI );
    }
}

class SizedFrame extends JFrame { public SizedFrame( String title ) { super( title ); setSize( 320, 200); } };
class AddDeptFrame extends SizedFrame { public AddDeptFrame() {super("DeptFrame"); } };
class AddEmpFrame extends SizedFrame { public AddEmpFrame() {super("EmpFrame"); } };
class AddSalgradeFrame extends SizedFrame { public AddSalgradeFrame() {super("SalgradeFrame"); } };
```

Если все-таки надо сделать условный оператор (очень разная обработка условий, которую нельзя/не хочется закинуть в несколько классов-обработчиков), можно воспользоваться свойством `ButtonModel` `actionCommand`.

При создании кнопки установить свойство `button.setActionCommand("command-text")`, а при обработке нажатия делать `String command = rbg.getSelection().getActionCommand()` и дальше в зависимости от результата что-то делать.

Comment: я java начал изучать 2 месяца назад, но такого я еще не видел, честно говоря поражен. Спасибо большое за ваш ответ, попробую и подробней ознакомлюсь со стримами

Comment: хотя такое представление, пока тяжелое для восприятия

Comment: Переписал ответ: стрим оказался лишним, т.к. `ButtonGroup` возвращает выбранный элемент, который можно потом искать в таблице.

Comment: Спасибо большое, по пробую